# How do I create a one-to-many relationship with a default one-to-one property for I18N

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Suppose we have these classes:

```
class Item(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String)
    i18ns = relationship("ItemI18n", backref="item")

class ItemI18n(Base):
    lang_short = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

The idea here is to have this item's name in multiple languages, for example in English and German. This works fine so far, one can easily work with that. However, most times, I am not interested in all (i.e. both) names but only the users locale.

For example, if the user is English and wants to have the name in his language, I see two options:

```
# Use it as a list
item = session.query(Item).first()
print item.data, [i18n.name for i18n in item.i18ns if i18n.lang_short == "en"][0]

# Get the name separately
item, name = session.query(Item, ItemI18N.name).join(ItemI18N).filter(ItemI18N.lang_short == "en").first()
print item.data, name
```

The first one filters the list, the second one queries the language separately. The second is the more efficient way as it only pulls the data really needed. However, there is a drawback: I now have to carry around two variables: `item` and `name`. If I were to extend my `ItemI18N` for example, add a `description` property, then I would query for `ItemI18N` and carry those around.

But business logic is different: I would expect to have an `Item` with a `name` and `description` attribute, so that I would do something like this:

```
item = session.query(Item).first()
print item.data, item.name
```

So that's where I want to go: Pull all those attributes from `Item18N` directly into `Item`. And of course, I would have to specify the language anywhere. However, I cannot find any recipes for this since I don't even know what to search for. Can SQLAlchemy do such a thing?

I also created a [complete example](http://pastebin.com/Ea1Bqzcw) for everything I described (except of course the part I don't know how to realize).

**Edit**: I have played around a bit more to see whether I can come up with a better solution and so far, I have found one way that works. I initially tried to realize it with `Query.get` but this doesn't work beyond my simple example, because reality is different. To explain, I have to extend my initial model by adding a `Language` table and turn `ItemI18N` into a many-to-many relationship with the primary key being `(lang_id, item_id)`:

```
class ItemI18N(Base):
    lang_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('language.id'), primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    language = relationship("Language", lazy="joined")


class Language(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    short = Column(String)
```

Now to get my correct locale I simply turn all loadings into joined loadings by applying `lazy="joined"` to the complete path. This will inevitable pull in all languages thus returning more data than I need. My approach is then completely independent of SQLAlchemy:

```
class Item(Base):
    ...
    i18ns = relationship("ItemI18N", backref="item", cascade="all, delete-orphan", lazy="joined")

    def name(self, locale):
        for i18n in self.i18ns:
            if i18n.language.short == locale:
                return i18n.name
```

But this is not a pretty solution, both because of the overhead of retrieving *all* I18N data from the database and then fitering that result back to *one* thus making it completely irrelevant that I pulled all in the first place (since the locale will stay the same the whole time). My [new full example](http://pastebin.com/iSTkESjg) shows how only one query is executed and gives my transparent access - but with an ugly overhead I would like to avoid.

The example also contains some playing around with [transformations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#building-transformers) I have done. This could point to a solution from that direction, but I wasn't happy with this either because it required me to pass in the `with_transformation` part every time. I'd like it much better if this would automatically be applied when `Item` is queried. But I have found no event or other for this.

So now I have multiple solution attempts that all lack the ease of direct access compared to the business logic described above. I hope someone is able to figure out how to close these gaps to produce something nice and clean.

Comment: It sounds to me that what you want is a proxy object that acts as an `Item`, but will lookup the item's name based on the users language automatically.  Is that about right?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I am looking for.